# VGA VS HDMI for 19" display

Tags: display, hdmi, vga

Is there any different in resolution if I hooked up my laptop into a display with VGA cable rather than HDMI?

Okay this question seems obvious and have been answered before **but what if I have small display like 19inch?!**

Comment: (1) Historically 19" is not a *"small"* display.  It is probably larger than the display of your laptop.  (2) You fail to mention what resolution(s) the monitor is capable of. (3) You fail to mention the aspect ratio of the monitor. (4) You fail to mention what output resolutions your laptop can drive this monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would surely depend on your usage (e.g., web browsing vs gaming) and the native resolution of both your laptop and monitor. In general, you'll likely be plenty content with the VGA. I work pretty much every day with a 20 - 24 inch 1080p monitor connected to my laptop and choose to use VGA over HDMI. If you're wanting to use audio out your monitor, then HDMI is probably a better route.

Answer (score -1):

HDMI the audio output will be from your the display. On VGA its still your system audio. Video output quality, I haven't seen much difference,as both my Laptop and Display are HD. for the black bars on top and bottom, you can change the aspect ratio(4:3 is what works well for me).